# Testing web application urls

Tags: http, testing, curl, web

I'm developing a **bookmarkable web application** having, let's say, fifty different url patterns which are accessed with different parameters. My aim is to have a test environment setting up a database with some predefined values. Later on, I would be interested in checking everything works fine, as an example:

- *GET* /myapp/login ✓
- *GET* /myapp ✓ Should be redirected to /myapp/login
- *POST* /myapp/login/post ✓ Authorize and store the cookie
- *GET* /myapp/securedurl ✓
- *GET* /myapp/anothersecuredurl?param=predefined ✓

I have tried a little bit with [cUrl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

**GET Login page**

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/myapp/login
```

Returns *200* code.

**POST for authorization**

```
curl -i  http://localhost:8080/myapp/login/post -X POST -d j_username="user" 
    -d j_password="pass" -c cookie.txt
```

Performs the login properly and stores the authorized cookie, but it returns *302 Moved* (As it's expected because I perform a redirection to home page).

**GET some secured url**

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/myapp/securedurl -b cookie.txt
```

The secured resource is properly accesed, but I'm using a url rewriting framework, so it forces a redirection and *302* code is returned again.

The problem I'm dealing with *cUrl* is that it's request specific, so I can't check redirections properly performed. Also even if I could get them properly working, I would need to parse each of the responses to check their code.

So probably I need to emulate a browser behaviour to check the whole cycle instead of focusing in each of the requests.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up using [Selenium Web Driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) and its java API in order to make the tests. The performed steps are:

- *GET* the login page
- Fulfill the login form
- Iterate over all the possible urls and check they're properly loaded

I perform it with this code piece:

```java
/*
*   Constants declaring the urls to test
*/
private static final String[] URLS = { URL1, URL2, URL3 };

/*
*   Here we've to check that the return page is 404. In my case this comparison works, 
*   however it may vary for different implementations of web applications 
*/
private boolean check404(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.getPageSource().contains("404.xhtml");
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(APP_URL + "/login");

    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Login");

    WebElement formName = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
    formName.sendKeys("user@gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(50);
    WebElement formPassword = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
    formPassword.sendKeys("password1");
    formName.submit();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(APP_URL + "/home"));

    // Get some nonexistent url and check that returns 404 code
    driver.get(MODULE_URL + "/sss");

    Assert.assertTrue(check404(driver));

    logger.info("Checking " + URLS.length + " of the application");

    for (String url : URLS) {
        driver.get(url);
        logger.info("Checking " + url);
        //I look for the title here, to verify it's properly loaded. 
        //This implementation may also vary
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals("MyApp Title"));
        Assert.assertFalse(check404(driver));
    }

    driver.quit();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Interesting example ...

[Swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) DSL is kind of tool to easy handle such issue but **still using curl**! Yes, curl is request oriented as you said, and it's true. Sometimes it's problem.

Swat uses curl as well (under the hood), but swat allows *sequential http (curl) requests* - called [swat modules](https://github.com/melezhik/swat#upstream-and-downstream-stories) which are just *reusable* http requests. Like for end user this is a single use case splitted under the hood on many multiples curl requests:

Let me rewrite your selenuim example to swat:

**$ mkdir -p myapp/login/post**

**$ nano  myapp/login/post/swat.ini**

```
swat_module=1 # this is reusable curl request
curl_params="-c ${test_root_dir}/cookie.txt -d j_username='%username%' -d j_password=%password%"
```

**$ nano  myapp/login/post/post.txt**

```
# authentication post should succeed
200 OK
# should see http redirect code at headers
302
# this is where we are redirected upon successful login
generator: [ resource().'/HOME' ]
```

**$ mkdir -p myapp/check_secured_urls**

**$ nano  myapp/check_secured_urls/hook.pm**

```
# this is a fake resource is not going to be requested 
# spoofing server response
set_response('OK');

run_swat_module(
  POST => '/login/post', {
    username => 'j_username',
    password => 'password1'
  }
)

# GET secured urls
# we should succeed as we already authenticated
   for my $uri ( qw{ FOO FOO/BAR FOR/BAR/BAZ } ) {
         run_swat_module( GET => '/any_url', { uri => $uri }  )
   }
```

**$ nano  myapp/check_secured_urls/get.txt**

```
# this is spoofed server response
OK
```

**$ mkdir -p myapp/any_url/**

**$ nano myapp/any_url/get.txt**

```
200 OK
# always should see this one? 
# not very clear from your example 
<title>MyApp Title</title>
```

**$ nano myapp/any_url/swat.ini**

```
swat_module=1 # this is reusable curl request
curl_params="-b ${test_root_dir}/cookie.txt"
```

**$ nano myapp/any_url/hook.pm**

```
# this is just adapter to GET ANY url:
# so we need dynamically set requested resource:

modify_resource( sub {  module_variable('uri') } );
```

And finally last one , check none existed pages return 404

**$ mkdir myapp/sss**

**$ echo 'ignore_http_err=1' > myapp/sss/swat.ini**

**$ echo 'try_num=1' >> myapp/sss/swat.ini**

**$ echo '404' > myapp/sss/get.txt**

$ swat ./ localhost:8080

PS No need to implement check404 for secured URLs as swat does this for you by default.

DISCLOSURE  - I am the author of swat.